# How to turn off the webcam in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, synchronization, webcam

I am trying the turn of the webcam using javaScript in React but when I shifted to the new component or when a component destroyed my react component immediately move to the next page but my web cam light is still on in new component

I am using following method to turn off the camera before shift to the new page

```
  const video = document.getElementById("modelvideo")
  const stream = video.srcObject
  const tracks = stream.getTracks()
  tracks.forEach(function (track) {
    track.stop()
  })
  video.srcObject = null;
  navigate('/newcomponent')
```

i want to move to new component when my webcam is off. how can I solve this problem to achieve synchronize behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting stream from DOM like does not give you your original stream object

```
const video = document.getElementById("modelvideo")
const stream = video.srcObject
```

In order to Stop your stream you have to save the original stream object in a variable where it is created
forexample:

```
    let stream = null
 // Start the camera stream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
  .then(function(mediaStream) {
    stream = mediaStream;
 
    document.querySelector("video").srcObject = stream;
  });

// Stop the camera stream
function stopCamera() {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
  });
}
```

for more info read this [Open Camera stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) and [stop camera stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop)

Comment: Does this work? I have tried this and the light remains on...

Comment: When you open a stream using a stream object, you can turn off the camera by using that same stream object. However, it's important to note that if you change the stream object, the previous stream will remain open. So, to properly turn off the camera, you must use the original stream object that was used to open the stream

Comment: Is there a way to see all the streams that are open and just close all of them?